# How to check if input in the list

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to build a suggestion tool based on a movie dataset. More specifically it will suggest a movie by title based on genre keyword.

But I couldn't pass the loop/check part of the script, here is what I have tried:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import random

#CSV READ & GENRE-TITLE
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df_title = data["title"]
df_genre = data["genre"]

#TOKENIZE
tokenized_genre = [word_tokenize(i) for i in df_genre]

choice = {}

while choice != "exit":
    choice = input("Please enter a word = ")
    for word in {choice}:
        if word in df_genre:
            """The random title of the random adventure movie will be implemented here"""  
        else:
            print("The movie of the genre doesn't exist")
```

The output of the `tokenized_genre` like this:

```
[['Biography', ',', 'Crime', ',', 'Drama'],
 ['Drama'], ['Drama', ',', 'History'],
 ['Adventure', ',', 'Drama', ',', 'Fantasy'],
 ['Biography', ',', 'Drama'],
 ['Biography', ',', 'Drama', ',', 'Romance']
```

The output of the loop:

```
Please enter a word = adventure
The movie of the genre doesn't exist
Please enter a word = Adventure
The movie of the genre doesn't exist
```

I guess the mistake in the list of the tokenized words but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: What is stored exactly in `df_genre`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use:

```
search = {e.lower() for l in tokenized_genre  for e in l}
choice = input("Please enter a word = ")
while choice != "exit":
    if choice.lower() in search:
        # TODO: The random title of the random adventure movie will be implemented here
         print("Works!")  
    else:
        print("The movie of the genre doesn't exist")
    choice = input("Please enter a word = ")
```

`search` is a set containing all your words from `tokenized_genre` only once, the benefit is that the search in a set is O(1) time complexity also since your `choice` variable is a `word` you could check dirctly if the  input word is in the `search` set

Comment: @ilkebirsen check now

Comment: ah, didn't know that function also lowers the letters, thought it only checks whether the letter is lower. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, I'm not a Python master.

It seems that df_genre returns a "list of list" not a list. You should join the lists and then search there.

```
import itertools

df_genre = [['Biography', ',', 'Crime', ',', 'Drama'], ['Drama'], ['Drama', ',', 'History'], ['Adventure', ',', 'Drama', ',', 'Fantasy'], ['Biography', ',', 'Drama'], ['Biography', ',', 'Drama', ',', 'Romance']]

#TOKENIZE
joined_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df_genre))

choice = {}

while choice != "exit":
    choice = input("Please enter a word = ")
    for word in {choice}:
        if word in joined_list:
            """The random title of the random adventure movie will be implemented here"""  
            print("Works!")
        else:
            print("The movie of the genre doesn't exist")
```

[Result of local test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1huT.png)

I don't know if it is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it didn't worked after i implemented it for the genre list. the `df_genre` list has more items than i wrote there. I guess the reason of the different results is that. Also the other method is worked but thanks anyway.